# ASP.NET I don't get a value from textbox field on GridView RowUpdating event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So the problem is i don't get get a value from textbox field on GridView RowUpdating event.

Here is HTML ASP.net code:

```
<asp:GridView
    ID="GridView3"
    DataKeyNames="anPeriodID,acWorkerID"
    Visible ="true"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
    OnRowUpdating="GridView3_RowUpdating"  
    OnRowEditing="GridView3_RowEditing"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView3_RowCancelingEdit"         
    CssClass="display table table-striped table-bordered">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acPeriod" HeaderText="Obdobje" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acWorker" HeaderText="Zaposleni" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acReason" HeaderText="Vzrok za +/- 15 ur" ItemStyle-Width="85%" ControlStyle-Width="100%"/>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Button_edit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="edit" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-warning myconfirm" ToolTip="Uredi"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-120"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="Button_delete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="delete" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ToolTip="Izbriši"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash bigger-120"></i></asp:LinkButton> --%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-success" ToolTip="Potrdi"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-120"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ToolTip="Prekliči"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-reply bigger-120"></i></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" SelectCommand="_upJN_GetPeriodData" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="acUserID" SessionField="USERID" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBox1" Name="all" PropertyName="Checked" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBox2" Name="curr" PropertyName="Checked" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="type" DbType="Int16" DefaultValue="2" /> 
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And here is code behind:

```
protected void Grid_Reload(int i)
{
    DB db = new DB();

    if (i == 0 || i == 1)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = db.GetConnString();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    if (i == 0 || i == 2)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = db.GetConnString();
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
    if (i == 0 || i == 3)
    {
        SqlDataSource3.ConnectionString = db.GetConnString();
        GridView3.DataSource = SqlDataSource3;
        GridView3.DataBind();
    }    
}

protected void GridView3_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    String warning_msg = "", error_msg = "", info_msg = "", success_msg = "";
    int i = 0;
    Commons cm = new Commons();
    try
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int periodid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        string workerid = GridView3.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();

        TextBox field1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];

        String SQL = "update _utJN_EvidencaDCSum set acReason = '" + field1.Text + "' where anPeriodID = '" + periodid.ToString() + "' and acWorkerID = '" + workerid + "'";

        DB db = new DB();
        db.ExecSQL(SQL);

        GridView3.EditIndex = -1;
        Grid_Reload(3);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error_msg = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        i = cm.SetMessage(LabelError, error, error_msg, LabelWarning, warning, warning_msg, LabelInfo, info, info_msg, LabelSuccess, success, success_msg);
    }

    if (i == 1)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#msg';", true);
    }
}

protected void GridView3_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView3.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    Grid_Reload(3);
}

protected void GridView3_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    Grid_Reload(3);
}
```

The problem is I assume here:

```
TextBox field1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
```

But I cannot figure it out. 
I have almost identical example, but it's working perfectly.

Other method (that one is working just fine):

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    String warning_msg = "", error_msg = "", info_msg = "", success_msg = "";
    int i = 0;
    Commons cm = new Commons();
    try
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

        TextBox field1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];

        String SQL = "update _utJN_Holidays set acText = '" + field1.Text + "' where anID = '" + id.ToString()+ "'";

        DB db = new DB();
        db.ExecSQL(SQL);

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        Grid_Reload();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error_msg = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        i = cm.SetMessage(LabelError, error, error_msg, LabelWarning, warning, warning_msg, LabelInfo, info, info_msg, LabelSuccess, success, success_msg);
    }

    if (i == 1)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#msg';", true);
    }
}
```

I tried also this:

```
//Loop through all Cells in the Row.
int index = 0;
foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
{
    if (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        //Check whether Cell has TextBox.
        if (cell.Controls[0] is TextBox)
        {
            //Reference the TextBox.
            TextBox textBox = cell.Controls[0] as TextBox;
            textBox.ID = "txtReason";
            //warning_msg += "xx" + GridView3.HeaderRow.Cells[index].Text + "xx" + index.ToString();
        }
    }
    index++;
}

//TextBox field1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
TextBox field1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtReason");

String SQL = "update _utJN_EvidencaDCSum set acReason = '" + field1.Text + "' where anPeriodID = '" + periodid.ToString() + "' and acWorkerID = '" + workerid + "'";
```

and its still empty..

Answer (score 2):

you could do it another way as put 
`TextBox textname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("your textbox id");`
and then use its value where you want code behind

Comment: How do i know TextBox ID? Text box is autogenerated, when i click on edit buton.

Comment: Hmmm.. if i loop through all Cells in the Row , and check if  cell is a textbox.. i get index 2...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured it out. The problem is basicly in Page_Load method, because it has always reloaded Grid3..

correct code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["USERNAME"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Grid_Reload(3);

    }

    Grid_Reload(1);
    Grid_Reload(2);
}
```